# Copy file from FTP to ADLS using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am copying a file from FTP server to ADLS using ADF. I want to check whether the source file is completely copied in ADLS  or not. How we can achieve this in ADF ?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the file properties to check if the file is completely copied.

You can use parameters in ADF to find this.

Maybe you can derive File Size at source and sink and them compare, you can compare file names as well to check if all files are copied.

You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124963/how-to-add-a-validation-in-azure-data-factory-pipeline-to-check-file-size) to have an idea of how to check file size.

Or, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425912/azure-data-factory-copy-data-if-a-certain-file-exists) to check if file exists at destination or not after Copy

Comment: Hi @Shivam : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !